# detect all image sizes on page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some JavaScript, that will allow me to scan the page and search for specific image sizes and outline said image in red.  Example: I want to find all instances of images that are exactly 50x50px or 65x65px and outline them.

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var img;
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  img = images[i];
  if ((img.clientWidth == "_whatyouwant_") && (img.clientHeight == "_whatyouwant_")) {
      img.className = img.className + " hightlight";
  }
}
```

We take all the images, we check the size and if it's equal to *whatyouwant* you apply a class that defines the additional style.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('theidhere');
for(var a = 0; a <= image.length; a++) {
    var image = img[a];
    var width = image.clientWidth;
    var height = image.clientHeight;
}
```

These are the data attached to the image property that would get the current properties of the element relative to the Browser.

Then you can run a simple if block to check for the conditions, example:

```
if(width == 50 && height == 50) {
  /* set the outline or a class */
}
```

The object data have a better documentation at Mozilla Developer Network.

clientWidth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth

clientHeight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight

Comment: I have the code, I missed the iteration part sorry!

Comment: Ehh... where does `image` come from? Why override `image = img[0]`, `img[0]` is `undefined` and the loop would stop...